# Selection of data with 31 days or above gap between each of the row for same primary key column value?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Ex: data set:

```
id             Encounter_date                
1              01-01-2020          
1              17-01-2020 
1              20-01-2020        
1              02-02-2020        
1              14-02-2020 
1              17-02-2020      
1              04-03-2020 
1              15-03-2020       
1              06-04-2020        
1              15-04-2020        
1              07-05-2020 
1              10-05-2020         
1              19-07-2020
1              21-07-2020        
1              19-08-2020        
1              01-12-2020
```

Assumption: No duplication with same encounter_date and id

For an id
1.I have to select least date encounter_date as the first encounter

2. 2nd encounter  should be >= 31 days of the first encounter
3. 3rd encounter should be of >= 31 days of the second encounter
4. 4th encounter should be of >= 31 days of the 3rd encounter

and so one ...

Any ideas to achieve this in SQL which should write against redshift database!

Expected output :

```
 id     Encounter_date              difference in days
 1      01-01-2020                  0           
 1      02-02-2020                  32
 1      04-03-2020                  31
 1      06-04-2020                  33
 1      07-05-2020                  31
 1      19-07-2020                  73
 1      19-08-2020                  31
 1      01-12-2020                  104
```

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Please tag the question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...? The actual solution might really depends on this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENTS
(
PATIENT_ID INT,
ENCOUNTER_DATE DATE
)

CREATE TABLE PATIENTS_TARGET
(
PATIENT_ID INT,
ENCOUNTER_DATE DATE
)
TRUNCATE TABLE PATIENTS;
INSERT INTO PATIENTS
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-01-01' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE
UNION
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-01-17' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE
UNION
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-01-20' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE
UNION
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-02-02' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE
UNION
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-02-14' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE
UNION
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-02-17' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE
UNION
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-03-04' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE
UNION
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-03-15' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE
UNION
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-04-06' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE
UNION
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-04-15' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE
UNION
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-05-07' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE
UNION
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-05-10' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE
UNION
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-07-19' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE
UNION
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-07-21' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE
UNION
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-08-19' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE
UNION
SELECT 1 AS PATIENT_ID ,'2020-12-01' AS ENCOUNTER_DATE

--TRUNCATE TABLE PATIENTS_TARGET
--SELECT * FROM PATIENTS_TARGET

SELECT DISTINCT ENCOUNTER_DATE INTO #DATE FROM PATIENTS
ORDER BY ENCOUNTER_DATE
--SELECT * FROM #DATE

DECLARE @DATE_I DATE,@END_DATE DATE
SELECT @DATE_I=MIN(ENCOUNTER_DATE) FROM #DATE
SELECT @END_DATE=MAX(ENCOUNTER_DATE) FROM #DATE
WHILE @DATE_I<=@END_DATE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO PATIENTS_TARGET
SELECT PATIENT_ID
,ENCOUNTER_DATE
FROM
(SELECT 
P.PATIENT_ID,
P.ENCOUNTER_DATE,
CASE WHEN T.PATIENT_ID IS NULL THEN 1 
WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,MAX(T.ENCOUNTER_DATE),P.ENCOUNTER_DATE)>=31 THEN 1
ELSE 0 
END AS FLAG
 FROM PATIENTS P
LEFT JOIN PATIENTS_TARGET T
ON P.PATIENT_ID=T.PATIENT_ID
WHERE P.ENCOUNTER_DATE=@DATE_I
GROUP BY P.PATIENT_ID,
P.ENCOUNTER_DATE,
T.PATIENT_ID
)AS A
WHERE FLAG=1

SET @DATE_I= DATEADD(DAY,1,@DATE_I)
END
```

Comment: sangeeth, Reformatted the question and example data set, please give me an idea to implement

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=44c43bb838fd49c203149ecabbae03ea

Answer (score 0):

knowing if there really exist records every 31 days is a difficult task,

see: [dbfille](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=04dac0be3fe2767ffedcb80f428079b0)

output:

```
patient_id  Encounter_date  previousDate    NrDays  code
1   2020-01-01          XXX
1   2020-01-17  2020-01-01  -16 YYY
1   2020-02-02  2020-01-17  -16 MM
1   2020-02-14  2020-02-02  -12 cc
1   2020-03-04  2020-02-14  -19 nn
2   2020-01-10  2020-03-04  54  XXX
2   2020-02-03  2020-01-10  -24 YYY
2   2020-02-14  2020-02-03  -11 MM
2   2020-02-16  2020-02-14  -2  cc
2   2020-03-24  2020-02-16  -37 nn
```

Comment: Encounter need not be exactly on 31 days it could be min record of 31 days or above after 1st encounter , still, this is not possible?

Comment: I re-read you comment a couple of times, but..... i do not understand what you are trying to say...

Comment: Luuk , I mean to ask , is this problem can't be solved or questions not framed properly?

Comment: The answer is: YES.   Both question is not completely clear, and that's why it maybe is not possible to solve. if you give more details (1 patient, but more data) as input, and desired output, than maybe a better answer is possible but SO is not about solving problems, it's about helping to find a correct answer which helps the person who is asking to solve his own problem.

Comment: Luuk, Hope this time I framed the question properly, please have look

Comment: The output from the solution in the answer from `sangeeth` looks OK ?

Comment: The solution is specific to the SQL server, to make to work in Redshift I had to choose an alternative of UDF in redshift, still, it is a great support thank you.